# Not able to setup Default org in VS code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

[image]

Previously I have setup sandbox as a Default Org in my VS code. But somehow it's not showing now and when I am trying to setup again, I am not able to do so as commands are not showing in Command Palette. Tried to set it using CLI but it is not happening.

Can anyone help here please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your extension are then not activated, activate it by running create project command in command pallete.

Comment: I have tried reloading the extensions and re-installing it as well but no luck. I am getting error as "Command SFDX: Create Project With Manifest resulted in error (command sfdx.force.project.with.manifest.create not found)"

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I have downgraded the version of Salesforce CLI Integration in Salesforce extension pack from 58.13.1 to 58.11 and it works.